# ListView to cover entire screen in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have implemented a listview in my Android app (API 8). However, the list consists of only three elements and hence, more than half of the screen is empty. I want to expand the listview to cover the entire screen of the phone. What are some ways to do the same?

Here is my layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@color/white"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:weightSum="100"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:id="@+id/test_image"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/footer"
        android:src="@drawable/logo1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="60" 
        android:prompt="@string/city_prompt"
        />
</LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"   
    >
    <ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    />


</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Please note that I want the list items to cover the entire screen, with just three items in place.

Comment: Remove the parent of ListView that is LinearLayout and try. Also I have the same problem that listView doesn't fill up the entire screen.

Comment: See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943410/listview-doesnt-occupy-whole-screen

Comment: could you try with android:dividerHeight ?

Answer (score 2):

ListView won't fill all the space automatically. If you want to achieve this, because here, ListView is taking the full space, but not its items. If you still want to make bigger rows, in case of lesser items, then provide the height of list items, in the getView method using the getCount() method.

For example, you want to display maximum six items at a time on screen in the list. Then Implement ListView like this:

Get width and height of screen, using the following code into the onCreate method:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Now in getView, do the following:

```
int itemHeight = 0;
if (getCount() >= 6)
    itemHeight = height/6;
else
    itemHeight = height/getCount();

LinearLayout llView=new LinearLayout(YourActivityName.this);
//Or inflate through XML

llView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.Fill_Parent, itemHeight));
//Do other functionality
```

Comment: Can you please explain this in detail?

Comment: Hey! thanks for that :)
I pasted the first code in the onCreate method. However,it was showing an error on display.getSize(size); (Error: The method getSize(Point) is undefined for the type Display)

Also, can you please tell me how do I put the second code. I don't have a getView function at the moment!

Comment: hey, will you please let me know how to go about it, in detail?

Answer (score 2):

I just copied your XML, pasted and tried, and it works fine. One more thing to tell is that you should not use `layout_height="wrap_content"`. Instead you can give it as `android:layout_height="0dip"` as you have already used `android:layout_weight="1"` which will make ListView fill the remaining area of your LinearLayout.

Comment: No this will not work if you have less number of rows you should find a way how to increase the row height of the list view.

Answer (score 1):

First change:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
>
```

Tthen second, change:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
/>
```

Comment: That's because fill_parent=match_parent.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent-property-in-android

Comment: @rahulritesh Use layout inflater make your own row and set Height of that row.